# Can $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^2$ be embedded into an orientable 3-manifold?

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, projective-space

We know that $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^2$ cannot be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^3$, but is there an orientable 3-manifold where it is possible?

Comment: What about $\Bbb R \Bbb P^3$?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, the obvious vector space inclusion $\iota: \mathbb{R}^3 \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$, or its restriction $\iota\vert_{\mathbb{S}^2} : \mathbb{S}^2 \hookrightarrow \mathbb{S}^3$, induces an embedding of $\mathbb{RP}^2$ into $\mathbb{RP}^3$, and the latter is orientable.

Comment: The same is true for the Klein bottle. It cannot be embedded in $R^3$ but it can be embedded in an oriented 3 manifold. The quotient of $R^3$by the standard lattice of translations together with the affine transformation, (x,y,z) -> (x +1/2, -y, -z) is such a manifold. The Klein bottle is the projection of the (x,y) plane into the quotient manifold. For both $RP^2$ and the Klein bottle their normal bundles in the 3 manifolds are non-trivial.